# Why does an SSH public key used to authenticate SSH seem to expire after a while?

Tags: ssh, public-key-encryption

I want to SSH from client to server without a password, so I append client's public key to server's `authorized_keys`. While previously I needed a password, immediately after I do the above, I don't need the password anymore. Hence I conclude I know how to do this and it works.

But then, some time after that it fails. I then have to generate a new public/private key pair on the client, append the public key to the server, and again it works for a while only.

Why would that be??

I restarted the server's SSH daemon and it did not help.  Appending the old key again does not work. I have to generate  a new one and append that.

I tried a different account on the client - root. Same problem.

Comment: How long did you make the certificate valid for?

Comment: don't know anything about certificates - I am just using >ssh-keygen -t rsa or rda

Comment: I grepped manpage for certificates, and my understanding is that this is an optional functionality, which I don't need.  I just want to ssh from client to server, both are local.

Comment: @Ramhound, SSH keys aren't certs, and they don't have an expiration date mechanism.

Comment: You can use certificate to authenticate SSH connections.  Infact "Also certificate authentication is performed via the public-key authentication method. Instead of the client sending just a public key, it sends a certificate containing a public key." so my comment is entirely without reason.

Comment: This is an old question, but I would guess the issue is some change in the RSA encryption on the client machine versus the server machine? I imagine if the server is updated regularly but the client isn’t, the accepted RSA encryption level or standard (honestly my brain is blanking on the right word here) would be rejected until a new key is generated on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Like you say, public or private keys don't expire. So this problem is probably not about that.

However, since this is all you tell about the problem:

> But then, some time after that it fails.

we can't really know how and for what reason it fails. You can enable debug output to see some more information about this.

I can make a guess though. One common cause is that the server you're trying to connect to changed its *server* keys due to some other reason - such as operating system reinstall -, or its ip has changed. Commonly your client recognizes any server it tries to connect to by its public key, and stores the public key together with what ip that information maps to (in known_hosts file). After a time these things tend to change, typically by change of ips by switching to different server or hosting provider, so at that point you'll need to do something. That something is not that you'd need to re-generate your keys, but refresh the server information instead and keep your keys as-is.

All the above is assuming you're really using public key authentication like you say. Also client certificate authentication is possible, and in that case, those certs of course do expire.

Answer (score 0):

We'd definitely need more info to see why the connection is periodically failing.

For future users, you can enable the output of debugging info with option `-v` such as in `ssh -v YOUR_USER@YOUR_SERVER` with up to a maximum of 3 v's, with each `v` increasing the verbosity of debugging info. From there you can see if the client is connecting successfully to the server, the public key exchange, the chosen cipher to encrypt the connection, if the server's public key is trusted, and if SSH authentication has succeeded. From `man ssh`:

```
 -v      Verbose mode.  Causes ssh to print debugging messages about its
         progress.  This is helpful in debugging connection, authentication,
         and configuration problems.  Multiple -v options increase the
         verbosity.  The maximum is 3.
```

Comment: Why would you ask someone who posted the question over eight years ago for more information?

Comment: The other post didn't address `how` to get the debugging info, and since I can't comment I can only answer to show how others to get this information.